# Purchased in Previous 12 Months from Date of Purchase - SQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new, and not even sure how to ask this question, but here goes:

For each customer/product purchase, I need to determine with SQL whether the same customer purchased that product in the 12 months prior to this purchase. So, if purchase is on 9/1/2018, I need to know if the customer purchased the same product in previous 12 months.

I've tried combinations of RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY but haven't really accomplished what I need to.

Edit: adding attempted code below:

```
select
   s.CUST_ACCT_ID
  ,s.PRODUCT
  ,s.BUS_MO  
  ,s2.BUS_MO

from INS_REF001_SALES_SUM_R48 s

left outer join INS_REF001_SALES_SUM_R48 s2
on s.CUST_ACCT_ID = s2.CUST_ACCT_ID
and s.PRODUCT = s2.PRODUCT
and s.BUS_MO < s2.BUS_MO
and s.BUS_MO >= dateadd(mm, datediff(mm, 0, s2.BUS_MO) - 12, 0)

inner join INS_REF006_ACCT a
on a.CUST_ACCT_ID = s.CUST_ACCT_ID
and a.CUST_ACCT_ID = s2.CUST_ACCT_ID

where s.BUS_MO between '11/01/2016' and '10/31/2018'
```

Thanks!
Scott

Comment: Good question. Usually showing table structure and example desired output will complement well with a well written description (like you've provided).

Comment: note MySQL dates are never represented in US wonky date format :-) only YYYY-MM-DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a self join:

```
SELECT a.customer_id, a.product_id, a.purchase_date, MAX(b.purchase_date) IS NOT NULL AS previous_12_months
FROM products a
LEFT JOIN products b
  ON a.product_id = b.product_id AND
     a.customer_id = b.customer_id AND
     b.purchase_date < a.purchase_date AND
     b.purchase_date >= a.purchase_date - INTERVAL 12 MONTH
GROUP BY a.customer_id
```

Comment: Thanks, danblack! I'll play around with your solution. I updated my question with a a sample of my code. Ideally, I'd like to return a "1" if there is a sale 12 months prior to purchase, and 0 if none.

Comment: should be closer, just need to join to customer data.

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you so much, danblack!